# Load related nested Entities of included List

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have an object which has a List of Sub-objects. I would like to project or load navigation properties (more than one) contained in each sub-object. Instead of trying to over-explain it I include the classes below.

```
public class Subject
{
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public int SubjectDescription { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher
{
    public int TeacherId { get; set; }
    public string TeacherName { get; set; }
}

public class StudentTimetableEntry
{
    public int StudentTimetableEntryId { get; set; }
    public int ClassId { get; set; }
    public Teacher ClassTeacher { get; set; }
    public Subject ClassSubject { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public List<StudentTimetableEntry> TimetableEntries { get; set; }
}
```

I then want to load a Student entry, including in the result the Student's `TimetableEntries`. That in itself is fine. I do it as follows and I think it is correct....

```
 using (MyDbContext ctx = new MyDbContext())
    {
        Student stud = ctx.Students
            .Include(
                        sa => sa.TimetableEntries.Select(te => te.ClassSubject)
                    ).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

but I would also like to load the ClassTeacher property (in addition to the ClassSubject property) associated with each TimetableEntry. There doesn't seem to be a way to `Select` more than one property though. I tried to `Select` an anonymous type...

```
        using (MyDbContext ctx = new MyDbContext())
        {
            Student stud = ctx.Students
                .Include(
                            sa => sa.TimetableEntries.Select(
                                te => new
                                {
                                    ClassSubject = te.ClassSubject,
                                    ClassTeacher = te.ClassTeacher
                                })
                        ).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

That resulted in the following error though:

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property
>   defined on the type

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong and how I can overcome this?

Many thanks

T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a string as well, as explain in [this article](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2010/10/03/entity-framework-using-include-with-lambda-expressions/).

In your case it would be someting like:

```
Student stud = ctx.Students.Include("TimetableEntries.ClassSubject")
```

Comment: Cheers Quarzy. Lovely stuff!

Answer (score 1):

To add to the Ouarzy's answer, to get both the `ClassSubject` and the `ClassTeacher`, you can append another Inlcude like so:

`Student stud = 
ctx.Students.Include("TimetableEntries.ClassSubject").Include("TimetableEntries.ClassTeacher")`